# Pushing changes to .json

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am trying to push a jsonobject in which i changed a parameter back into the json, i tried to do it like this:

```
fun edit_json(pos: Int) {
        var json: String?
        try {
            val inputStream: InputStream = assets.open("stempel.json")

            //reading stempel.json
            json = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

            var jsonarr = JSONArray(json)
            var jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(pos)
            jsonobj.put("sammelstatus", 1)

            val updatedJsonString = jsonobj.toString()
            
            val outputStream = this.openFileOutput("stempel.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val writer = OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)
            writer.write(updatedJsonString)
            writer.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
        }
    }
```

the jsonobject is changed succesfully, but i have problems with pushing them back to the json, somehow the writer dosent push them back into the .json which is located in my assets folder. Does anyone have an idea why this could be?

Chat gpt gave me multiple diffrent ways to push it like this one

```
val file = File(context.filesDir, "stempel.json")
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        outputStream.write(updatedJsonString.toByteArray())
        outputStream.close()
```

yet somehow none of these seem to be able to push the changed jsonobject back into the json

Answer (score 0):

In Android, the assets folder is read-only, which means you cannot directly write or modify files within it at runtime. That's why your attempts to write the updated JSON object back to the file in the assets folder are not working.

Instead, you should consider copying the file from the assets folder to the internal storage or external storage directory, where you have write access. Then, you can modify the copied file and save the changes successfully.